# Visual Studio 2012 Deploying WPF via ClickOnce missing Folder and Files

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

I have a WPF project that I am ready to deploy using Visual Studio 2012 but I'm running into a missing folder issue.

If I Start the project in VS it runs fine and my test button works as expected.

When I Publish the project, the publish succeeds, running setup.exe installs successfully and program starts to main window fine.

Clicking the test button crashes the application.

Line that causes crash:
`string[] reportFileNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("Reports");`

> "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\dirt\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\GEDD6PQW.N72\8M9ONPGG.TVB\prof..tion_40c30‌​d08e677b188_0001.0000_9a5540d4bfbe5aff\ **Reports'.**"

Confirmed Exists:
`C:\MyProject\bin\MyMode\Reports\`
`C:\MyProject\bin\MyMode\Reports\MyReport.rdlc`

Confirmed Does Not Exist: `C:\Users\dirt\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\GEDD6PQW.N72\8M9ONPGG.TVB\prof..tion_40c30‌​d08e677b188_0001.0000_9a5540d4bfbe5aff\Reports\`

The Reports\MyReport.rdlc files have a Build Action of `Resource` and Copy to Output Directory of `Copy always`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, was able to figure this one out rather quickly after typing that last sentence in the question...

In my case the `Reports\MyReport.rdlc` file had a build action of `Resource` and all I had to do was change it to `Content` (and make sure `Copy always` is set).

Solution:

**Right click File in Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Build Action -> Content**